# Do the rules of writing a structure in C vary with Turbo C++ compiler and GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, structure, typedef, turbo-c++

I have a singly linked list program in C. When i compile it on TC++ it has only 2 errors regarding some declaration(its fine). But when i compile it in Ubuntu using GCC, it has way too many errors. I have created a custom datatype called NODE for the members of the structure, but GCC wont accept it. And as i have used typedef, there is an error which says -

```
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’
```

Any rules i am missing out? Please help me!

---

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
typdef struct node
{
    int data;
    NODE *next;
}NODE;

//Creation Of the Nodes with NULL pointers
NODE* createnewnode()
{
    NODE* nn;
    nn=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(nn==NULL)
    {
        printf("Insufficient Memory");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter data");
    scanf("%d",&nn->data);
    nn->next=NULL;
    return(nn);
}


// Creation Of the Links
NODE* createlinkedlist(NODE *hn, int n)
{
    NODE *cn, *nn;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
        nn=createnewnode();
        if(hn==NULL)
        {
            hn=nn;
        }
else
        {
            cn->next==nn;
        }
    cn=nn;
    return(hn);
}

//Display of The Data
void display(NODE *hn)
{

    NODE *cn;
    for(cn=hn;cn!=NULL;cn=cn->next)
    {
        printf("\t %d, "cn->data);
    }
}

//Linear Searching
void search(NODE *hn, int n)
{
    NODE *cn;
    int i, x;
    printf("Enter the data to be found");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        if(x==cn->data)
        {
            printf("Data found at %d",i+1);
            break;
        }

        cn=cn->next;
        i=i++;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int n;
    NODE* hn=NULL;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes to be created");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    createlinkedlist(hn,n);
    display(hn);
}
```

---

Comment: If the compiler gives any form of error, the code is not fine. Different compilers may or may not show relevant errors after the first one, but don't count on it. The second error could be related to the first one etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with corrected `typedef` you can't use `NODE` inside its own declaration. Do a forward declaration of `NODE` first, or even better call it just `node`:

```
typedef struct node node;
struct node {
  ...
  node* next;
};
```

*Edit:* and other nitpicks:

- don't cast the return of `malloc`. If you feel the need for it, you are wrong somewhere else. (Here that you don't include `stdlib.h`)
- since long C has no default types for variables anymore. Your `i` in `createlinkedlist` is unknown and no modern compiler will let this through
- you have at least one place where you use a `==` operator instead of an assignment `=`. Always compile with all warnings enabled, any decent compiler should have found that.

Comment: Or drop the typedef and call it `struct node`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens Gustedt. I knew that `i` was undeclared. I was just trying to get the solution for the error
`expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’`
Will try the solution an get back soon.

Comment: Ok, I tried the solution, i wrote the structure as u mentioned and replaced all `NODE` with `node`. But still there are errors like this

http://imageshack.us/f/24/hhhhua.png/

Please ignore the undeclared `i`.

Comment: You still seem to have carried your typo of `typdef` instead of `typedef` from the start.

Comment: I feel like stabbing myself! HAHAHAHA!

Answer (score 0):

// correction of above asked code, but some logics of programmer are not /correct.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node // typedef spell
{
    int data;
   node *next;  // NODE was in upper case it should be in lower case
   node() //Constructor : i defined it in traditional way as extra
    {
        next = NULL;
        data = 0;
    }

}NODE;


//Creation Of the Nodes with NULL pointers
NODE* createnewnode()
{
    NODE* nn;
    nn=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(nn==NULL)
    {
        printf("Insufficient Memory");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter data");
    scanf("%d",&nn->data);
    nn->next=NULL;
    return(nn);
}


// Creation Of the Links
NODE* createlinkedlist(NODE *hn, int n)
{
    NODE *cn, *nn;
    int i;           // int i, was not defined, more correction fixed 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
        nn=createnewnode();
        if(hn==NULL)
        {
            hn=nn;
        }
else
        {
            cn->next==nn;
        }
    cn=nn;
    return(hn);
}
}
//Display of The Data
void display(NODE *hn)
{

    NODE *cn;
    for(cn=hn;cn!=NULL;cn=cn->next)
    {
        printf("\t %d", cn->data);
    }
}

//Linear Searching
void search(NODE *hn, int n)
{
    NODE *cn;
    int i, x;
    printf("Enter the data to be found");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        if(x==cn->data)
        {
            printf("Data found at %d",i+1);
            break;
        }

        cn=cn->next;
        i=i++;
    }
}

int  main()
{
    int n;
        NODE* hn=NULL;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes to be created");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    createlinkedlist(hn,n);
    display(hn);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```